# nsdateformatter --- convert string to date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I can't seem to get this right.
here is the original value I am receiving...
sDateOG NSString *  @"2015-02-24T11:06:10.847-05:00"    0x7cd09580

I am trying to turn that into nice and clean date/timestamp.

Still new at this, but what I thought was I should change this to a NSDATE, then I have options for the final format?

I can't seem to make this an nsdate though.
this is what I am trying...

```
    NSString *sDateOG = [variableArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'S''Z'"];
```

anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not quite everything.  First off, you don't need to quote `-` or `:`, just `T`.  Second, your single quotes are mismatched.  Third, it should be `SSS`, because there are 3 digits in the seconds fraction.  Fourth, for that form of timezone spec you need `ZZZZZ`.  It's all explained in [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), which you should bookmark.

Comment: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'yyyyMMddTHHmmSSSZZZZZ'"];
    NSDate *ddate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sDateOG];   still doesnt work... was that what you meant?

Comment: You do have to quote T.  And you need the - and : characters, just no need to quote them.

Comment: (Hint:  Read the spec.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the fractional seconds into account (and not quote anything expect special characters.)  This format string should work:

```
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'S.SSSZZZZZ"
```

Comment: It won't generate the right thing, but it seems to parse it just fine.

Comment: Went ahead and fixed it to generate and parse the time zone correctly instead of just parsing it.

Comment: No need for the quotes around `-` and `:`.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm a paranoid SOB and it's clearer to me which are formatting characters and which are fluff :)

Comment: I also fully parenthesize my expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting everything keyword (yyyy, MM, etc...) between quotes ?
You must also put as many keyword as digits/characters (hence the ZZZZZ).

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSZZZZZ"];
```

EDIT : Removed trailing useless quote

Comment: You do need to quote T.  And why the final single quote?

Comment: @hotlicks : Typed too fast :(